# how to create raw http responses in flask?

Tags: python, http, flask

I am working on a software that has a TCP Server that replies to requests done in a proprietary protocol.

Obviously the implementation relies on a socket listening on a fixed port and on analyzing and managing raw request and response.

I should add to this service the possibility to manage http requests.

I started using flask with the idea to let it manage templates rendering and responses creation, but I am a bit struck on the second part:

Righ now I managed to make this work with something like this:

```py
    with open(template_file) as f:
        template = f.read()
    app = flask.Flask('my app')  # create a context to render Response
    with app.app_context():
        context = {'title': 'mytitle', 
                'other_info':'.....',}
        rendered = flask.render_template_string(template, **context)
        response = flask.make_response(rendered)
        answer = f'''HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n {rendered} \n\n'''
    sock.sendall(answer.encode())
    sock.close()
```

In this case `make_response` creates a `Response` instance where you can get the rendered `html` code but going from Response to the raw `http` is my problem.

To solve this i have added manually a header, but I think that there is a better way in flask to do this but can't figure out.

To make the question more general: how can coexist flask web application with others? Where is the point on which I have to take control of the process?

Comment: You can always do: `response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'` etc

Comment: And then, how to get the raw http?

Comment: I think that what I need is to implement the WSGI server part as a layer between flask and raw level sockets.